# I'm getting confused about foldl and foldr in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

(\x acc -> acc + x*2) 0
I have this lambda for a fold function. If I use foldr, it returns the sum of the double of each element, as expected.

If I use foldl, it returns the sum of x*(2^pos_x) starting from the right and I have no idea why. Shouldn't they do the same thing in this case, but starting from different ends in the list?

Comment: In foldl, the accumulator is the first argument :)

Answer (score 4):

In `foldl`, the accumulator is the first argument of the folding function while in `foldr` it's the second argument. Consequently if you want to obtain the same result with `foldl` you should use the following function instead :

```
\acc x -> acc + x*2
```

Please note that here, you should get the same result,  because the operator you use is commutative and associative, but it's not always the case.

Comment: oh so the accumulator has to be first in the lambda, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`foldl` and `foldr` take functions of different types:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function given to `foldr` expects the accumulator as its second argument, while the function given to `foldl` expects the accumulator as its first argument.

If you have a function suitable for `foldr`, you can adapt it using the `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)` function:

```
> f x acc = acc + x*2
> foldr f 0 [1,2,3]
12
> foldl (flip f) 0 [1,2,3]
12
```